# CakePHP using ACL with MongoDB, AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, console, acl

I'm setting up an CakePHP app with ACL. I'm using MongoDB instead of MySQL. Everything works fine until I setup the ACL table. The ACL database is initialized. I want to setup some basic ACOs and AROs but failed. I can only create the nodes with parent set to root. Every time I add a node with parent, it gives me errors with the following error message.

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 53a8f92db238e52c08d63af1 ) "
```

Is this a problem with the CakePHP MongoDB datasource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's not going to work

CakePHP's ACL logic is built upon [the tree behavior](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.1/lib/Cake/Model/AclNode.php#L40), A behavior for storing hierarchical data in a relational database. MongoDB is a schemaless database, it doesn't have the restrictions which necessitate using the tree behavior for storing hierarchical data; putting them both together [is a very odd match](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/issues/42) (quoting myself):

> If you want to store tree structures in mongodb - MPTT is probably the least applicable model to use.

To use CakePHP's ACL implementation with MongoDB will require ensuring that the `lft` field in the ACO and ARO table is populated correctly.

### Is DB ACL *really* required

It's worth stating and giving serious consideration to *not* using DB ACL at all.

In the **vast** majority of (attempted) uses it's not really necessary at all here's a shortlist of questions to consider:

- Can all the rules be described in a few sentances such as "only owners can edit their records?"
- Are rules only created by developers setting up the app?
- Is performance a factor/concern?

If the answer to any one question is "Yes" - DB ACL is probably not the best solution to use.

Consider using [ini ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#defining-permissions-cakephp-s-ini-based-acl) or simply implement [isAuthorized](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) with controller-specific logic.